# get value spreaded on several strings with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have an issue parsing log file. The problem is some cells spread on several strings of a file.

[image]

Is there any way to get value in red square using regular expression?

Comment: Are spaces between columns, and begining of "empty" rows spaces or tabs? What flavour of regex?

Comment: Yes, spaces between columns. Empty rows - spaces. C# reg expression flavour

Comment: Иван, have you tried anything? What approach do you consider? I would read line by line, splitting the lines by tab, and in case all columns but Mmm command are empty, add the value from that column to the previous entry. No need in regex, really.

Comment: The task is to parse log with regex!!! (restriction of a frawework). Yes, i tried something. And my question was "is it possible to get mml_command splitted with some value with regex". Is it possible technically? Don't consider people are lazy fools!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't resist, so I wrote a simple example ;). It's not beautiful, but it might suit your needs. Check it out at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/08FqsC). Note that the text doesn't exactly match yours, and that you need to set the maximum number of lines in **one** log entry. This is done by regulating the number of `(?:\s+?(\S.*?)\n)?` ending the RE, as well as the number of additions of groups in the output.

The regex:

```
\d+\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\d+\s\d+\s(.*?)SUCCESS\d{4}.*?\n(?:\s+?(\S.*?)\n)?(?:\s+?(\S.*?)\n)?(?:\s+?(\S.*?)\n)?(?:\s+?(\S.*?)\n)?
```

A simple explanation is that it matches a line starting with a digit, skipping columns up to the "Mml Command" and then captures up to the "SUCCESSnnnn". It then optionally matches any following rows (up to 5 of them) beginning with a space.

Hope this helps.

Regards.